# How to interpret dots in an if statement?

Tags: fortran

What do the dots mean in the following code?

```
IF ((TAU.GE.dts).AND.(TAU.LE.(dts+dth))) THEN
  a = b+c
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Fortran90, the dots were required around operators. You can now use the `>=` instead of `.GE.` and `<=` instead of `.LE.`. Being one of the oldest languages, there are a lot of things still carried through and supported - spacing and operators are definitely among the more interesting features.

Fortran90 New Features (see relational operators): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/g77/Fortran-90-Features.html

Comment: Dots around operators are not just something ancient, if you use operator overloading and declare your own operators, you also use the dots. You also use them in logical operators today as rocky shows in his answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, You were of great help.

Answer (score 3):

The spacing is a little weird, although acceptable Fortran.  Binary comparitor and boolean expression operators like `.GE.`, `.LE.` and `.AND.` are tokens. So would this make more sense?:

```
IF ((TAU .GE. gts) .AND. (TAU .LE. (dts+dth)) THEN
```

In other words the program is checking that *TAU* is between *gts* and *dts* + *dth* including those endpoint values.

Comment: If this acceptable, click the check mark under the down arrow. It tells others looking to help others that this is solved, and your reputation will also increase.